# Writing partition function with divisor function

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions, divisor-sum

We know this identitiy.

$$P(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sigma _{1}(n-k)P(k)$$

where $P(n)$ is the partition function and $\sigma _{1}(n)$ is the divisor sum function. Can we pull partition function from this? I mean, i want to write partition function as $P(n)=f(\sigma _{1}(n))$ not $P(n)=f(P(n),\sigma _{1}(n))$.

Comment: The sum on the RHS does not go until $n$, i.e., we only have $np(n)=\sum_{r=1}^np(n-r)\sum_{m\mid r}m=\sum_{r=1}^np(n-r)\sigma(r).$ So no $p(n)$ on the RHS.

Comment: @Dietrich : so  $\sigma_1 \ast P(n) = 2  n P(n)$ i.e. $\sigma_1 = P^{-1} \ast (2n P(n))$ where $P^{-1}$ is the (additive) convolution inverse of $P$

Comment: You can't write $P(n) = f(\sigma_1(n))$ because there are pairs $m, n$ for which $\sigma_1(m) = \sigma_1(n)$ but $P(m) \not = P(n)$.  For example, $\sigma_1(6) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 12$ and $\sigma_1(11) = 1 + 11 = 12$, but $P(6) \not = P(11)$.

Comment: Is this question still active? I've just worked on this problem and could give a solution, but I see now, that expanding the formula already given by @DietrichBurde seems to give exactly my own proposal (which I derived using my own concepts&style). A draft (unfinished state) of that workouts can be peeked in at https://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/OnPartitionNumbers.pdf  . If still interested, I could put some of the ideas in a separate answer, but don't know whether there is really something worth to be added here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a famous identity to express $\sigma(n)$ by $p(n)$ using pentagonal numbers, e.g.,
$$
σ(n) = p(n − 1) + 2p(n − 2) − 5p(n − 5) − 7p(n − 7)
+ 12p(n − 12) + 15p(n − 15) − 22p(n − 22) − 26p(n − 26)+· · · ,
$$
but conversely we only get
$$
np(n) = σ(1)p(n − 1) + σ(2)p(n − 2) + σ(3)p(n − 3) · · ·+σ(n)p(0).
$$
If we consider the smaller values of $p(k)$ as given, this would be a formula of $p(n)$ in terms $\sigma(n)$, e.g.,
$$
p(n)=\sigma(n)+\sigma(n-1)+2\sigma(n-2)+3\sigma(n-3)+5\sigma(n-4)+7\sigma(n-5)+\cdots 
$$

Comment: DietrichBurde - could you give a source for your last equation? Or is it simply in WP?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms It is discussed in [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Topics-Theory-Numbers-Birkh%C3%A4user-Classics/dp/0817648372), for example.

Comment: DietrichBurde - ah, danke! (upps: thanks) Meanwhile I've looked at Weissstein's mathworld and found references for this formula. Phh, this function has been discussed in the broad & wide ... Hmm, perhaps there is not much to discover over that (for an half-amateur), perhaps I should leave my text-workout as it is...

Comment: ... hmm, I'm no more at university and don't have access to it library due to my retirement five years ago now. Shall not have the resources to engage with amazon... Thanks anyway for the link!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms It may also be contained in Apostol's book or another one, where a pdf-file is available. I have Grosswald's book at home. I can have a look whether or not there is more detail.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I had a look today. Grosswald gives much more detail. He also proves among other results that $$p(n)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j+1} \Bigl(p(n-(3j^2+j)/2)+p(n-(3j^2-j)/2)\Bigr)$$ with $p(n)=0$ for $n<0$, so that the sum is finite. It involves pentagonal numbers $j(3j-1)/2$. In my book it is page $116$ff.

Comment: DietrichBurde - again thanks for the help. Grosswald's seems to be an interesting book... I've seen that formula now elsewhere, but as well without proof. I do not yet know, whether my attempt to the problem is/contains/allows possibly another proof of those (now) two formulae. I'm currently being filled with thinking in my model, looking for generalizations, simplifications, errors and optimizations. I'll come back to this discussion in a serious way say a couple of days later. (First shall see for *.pdf of Apostol's book or from Weissstein's reference list then)